# docker container crashes while connecting to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am running a docker container on kubernetes cluster. When the below code is executed, container crashes with the following error.

```
import psycopg2 as psc


pq_conn = psc.connect(
    database=****,
    user=***,
    password=*****,
    host=*****,
    port=***
)


df= pd.read_sql_query("""
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
  LIMIT 1
""",
con= pq_conn)
```

crash log:
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)

I am using ubuntu:20.04 image. When I spin up a container using the same docker file on my mac m1, it works without any issues. I have tried with sqlalchemy create_engine function, similar error occurs. psycopg2 version 2.9.3 is used.

Please suggest if you have some hints.

Comment: I suspect you are running a docker container for the wrong architecture.